# How to divide one list into 2 using a For loop?

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a list called A and I want to divide it into two separate list B and C by looping through A and picking out one element to add to B and one to add to A throughout the length of A.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. You need to provide us with: the data, the criteria to `Select` elements, which `Cases` define how to `Split` the list, and most importantly: **the code of what you have tried so far**.

Comment: A hint: the best solution will not use a `For` loop, but probably something in the lines of `Select`, `Cases` or `Split`. Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because its unanswerable for lack of details. We can't help unless you [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, with all the details one would need to reproduce your problem exactly. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: A `For` loop is a very awkward and inefficient way to accomplish what you seek.  By what criterion do you place elements into $B$ or $C$?  Simple alternates?

Comment: Yes, Simple alternatives or even random separation

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `For`. Really. Never.

There are much more elegant ways, for example

```
a = Range[20];
{b, c} = Transpose[Partition[a, 2]]
```

> {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18,
>      20}}

or (should be the fastest; look up `Span` to understand it)

```
b = a[[1;; ;;2]]
c = a[[2;; ;;2]]
```

> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}
>
> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}

or

```
{b, c} = GatherBy[a, OddQ]
```

> {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18,
>      20}}

or

```
b = Select[a, OddQ]
c = Select[a, EvenQ]
```

> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}
>
> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}

In the last two examples, you may replace `OddQ` and `EvenQ` by any other function that returns `True` or `False` in order to realize other decision rules.

Comment: Only the middle approach is robust. +1 for it.

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, there is a special function for taking every other element called DownSample:

```
list = Range[20];
a = Downsample[list, 2]
b = Downsample[list, 2, 2]
```

a has all the odd values, b has all the evens.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = Range@20;
```

here are alternatives

```
TakeDrop[list, {1, -1, 2}]
```

> {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18,
>      20}}

and here is random separation

```
{d = RandomSample[s, Length@list/2], Complement[list, d]}
```

> {{4, 12, 5, 19, 3, 11, 17, 16, 6, 10}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15, 18,
>      20}}